SignalR Hub user still connected exception check
I am new to signalR hub implementation. There is code already written  on OnTokenValidated() event, as below.
Just wants to know, whether authenticating some client which was already authenticated might create a problem?
This code below throws 5XX errors when it throws InvalidOperationException exception. Can we just write a log line and continue with success instead of throwing this exception -
private Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    if (_mapping.GetConnectionId(context.Principal.Identity.Name, 
       out var _))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("User already 
        connected.");
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

here _mapping.GetConnectionId returns true for any active connections exist for this name.
Thanks in advance!

Hi @narane13, Of course you can log the event instead of throwing an exception.
